# In Unity, how do I get a specific texture in runtime from .psd file rather than its whole entire texture?

Tags: unity, 2d, textures, sprites

I'm trying to recreate the current texture on a SpriteRenderer's sprite in order to make it bigger so that I can add a white outline to it. This is all done on runtime.

[image]

[image]

If we look at the .psd file named testlayers and its structure, I am trying to use the pink pentagon named Polygon0 for this purpose.

Before starting the scene, all I have is a SpriteRenderer with Polygon0 referenced.

[image]

However, once I run the scene and my texture creation code, it grabs the entire .psd texture instead of Polygon0.

[image]

All my code does is try to get the texture of the current sprite by using Texture2D.GetPixels32(). The current sprite on the SpriteRenderer is named Polygon0. How do I get the texture of only Polygon0 and not the whole .psd?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - if you want a particular shape to be outlined, using an outline shader is likely to be a more direct solution. Is manipulating the .psd file a strong requirement or is the true end goal to have a way to add an outline to a target shape in the scene?

Comment: @Pikalek So I use a shader in order to give my sprite an outline. However, to get to that point, there is a preliminary step. I have a script that will take the current sprite on the SpriteRenderer, grab its texture,  create a new texture that is slightly bigger in dimensions than the grabbed texture, copy the pixels into the new texture, and then assign the new texture to the sprite. Then the sprite will have enough space to accomodate for the outline.

Comment: @Pikalek So ideally I'd like to grab only a selected shape that's separated by the PSB importer of the .psb (the polygon, the sphere, or the rectangle) and remake only the texture of that selected shape in order to give enough room for the sprite to apply the outline.